# Toggle an inactive element's text with jQuery

Tags: css, menu, slidetoggle, jquery

So I am attempting to create a menu element that shows and hides specific divs on a page, while also changing the text of the menu. After a little searching I have it worked out for the most part (although I know the code is a bit kludgey):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('.section[id="option1"]').click(function(){
                    $(this).text($(this).text() == 'OPTION1' ? 'OPTION1 >>' : 'OPTION1');
                    $('.blurb').not('.blurb[id="option1"]').hide();
                    $('.blurb[id="option1"]').slideToggle();
                });
            $('.section[id="option2"]').click(function(){
                    $(this).text($(this).text() == 'OPTION2' ? 'OPTION2 >>' : 'OPTION2');
                    $('.blurb').not('.blurb[id="option2"]').hide();
                    $('.blurb[id="option2"]').slideToggle();
                });
            $('.section[id="option3"]').click(function(){
                    $(this).text($(this).text() == 'OPTION3' ? 'OPTION3 >>' : 'OPTION3');
                    $('.blurb').not('.blurb[id="option3"]').hide();
                    $('.blurb[id="option3"]').slideToggle();
                });
            $('.section[id="option4"]').click(function(){
                    $(this).text($(this).text() == 'OPTION4' ? 'OPTION4 >>' : 'OPTION4');
                    $('.blurb').not('.blurb[id="option4"]').hide();
                    $('.blurb[id="option4"]').slideToggle();
                });
            $('.section[id="option5"]').click(function(){
                    $(this).text($(this).text() == 'OPTION5' ? 'OPTION5 >>' : 'OPTION5');
                    $('.blurb').not('.blurb[id="option5"]').hide();
                    $('.blurb[id="option5"]').slideToggle();
                });
            $('.section[id="option6"]').click(function(){
                    $(this).text($(this).text() == 'OPTION6' ? 'OPTION6 >>' : 'OPTION6');
                    $('.blurb').not('.blurb[id="option6"]').hide();
                    $('.blurb[id="option6"]').slideToggle();
                });
        });
```

(full code in action can be viewed [here](http://m35h.tumblr.com))

This code works for the most part, except that if you already have a certain element (class="blurb") shown, when you click on the menu item (class="section") for another element, the menu indicates that the other element is still open. It seems like there must be a simple way to append or remove the desired text on click, but I can't seem to find a good way of doing it. Would it be worth rewriting the code using something like [expander.js](http://plugins.learningjquery.com/expander/)?

Here is the effected html

```
<div class="nav">
    <div class="section" id="option1">option1</div>
    <div class="section" id="option2">option2</div>
    <div class="section" id="option3">option3</div>
    <div class="section" id="option4">option4</div>
    <div class="section" id="option5">option5</div>
    <div class="section" id="option6">option6</div>
 </div>

        <div class="blurb hidden" id="option1">
        <h1>content for option1</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="blurb hidden" id="option2">
        <h1>content for option2</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="blurb hidden" id="option3">
        <h1>content for option3</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="blurb hidden" id="option4">
        <h1>content for option4</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="blurb hidden" id="option5">
        <h1>content for option5</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="blurb hidden" id="option6">
        <h1>content for option6</h1>
    </div>
```

I'm still fairly new to jQuery, so any advice/pointers is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `id` **MUST** be unique.

Comment: Built you a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/sDrZ2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved your problem using a custom class and [`:after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3a%3aafter) CSS styles: http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/sDrZ2/3/

First, some CSS to append the arrows and convert to uppercase without modifying the text directly:

```
.uppercase {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.uppercase.arrowed:after { 
    content: " >>";
}
```

Add in some changes to your HTML to utilize [`data-`](http://api.jquery.com/data) attributes, remove duplicate IDs and add an `arrowed` class which the JS toggles:

```
<div class="nav">
    <div class="section arrowed" data-blurb="option1">option1</div>
    <div class="section arrowed" data-blurb="option2">option2</div>
    <div class="section arrowed" data-blurb="option3">option3</div>
    <div class="section arrowed" data-blurb="option4">option4</div>
    <div class="section arrowed" data-blurb="option5">option5</div>
    <div class="section arrowed" data-blurb="option6">option6</div>
</div>
```

And finally, a rewrite to [optimize](http://api.jquery.com/siblings) your JavaScript a lot:

```
 $('.section').click(function () {
     $(this).addClass('uppercase').toggleClass('arrowed')
         .siblings('.section').removeClass('arrowed');
     $('#'+$(this).data('blurb')).slideToggle()
         .siblings('.blurb').hide();
 });
```

Note that the `arrowed` class is toggled, so it needs to be added initially so that it's toggled off on the first click.

Comment: Thank you, that is very nearly perfect.The only issue now is that on the first click on an element, the section appears, but the arrow toggles off, making it reversed if a section is clicked more than once. You can see what I mean [here](http://jsfiddle.net/v2SaX/1/) by clicking on the "ABOUT" section twice.

Comment: You changed my code. Try removing the `arrowed` class from the initial HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/v2SaX/2/